Container script does not automatically run at the container start-up
I  just started learning about Docker and I am trying to create a project where I have producer, consumer and server scripts in seperate containers.Consumers update the table in sqlite3 database file in  app/data and I want to send api requests to reach them.
What I Expect:
I expect that producer and consumer to be running after kafka,zookeper and server container's health conditions are checked after that I expect to send api requests to my server container through localhost:5000 from my host machine
What actually happens:
kafka zookeeper ,server and producer containers works as expected but for some reason consumer container starts but do not log anything or show any sign that it  is executing script in cmd command in docker file
What I tried:
I checked all the scripts running inside containers and they work perfectly.I also using docker exec -it executed python script inside  of the consumer container and it worked perfect too it is just not executed after my docker compose up -- build  command. Lastly I changed port to be wrong and it logged error.
Edit:
I replaced my consumer.py code with arbitrary hello world.py and it worked expected.I think that problem is probably about in my consume script even though it works outside of the container with the correct port configuration so I am adding it here too.
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaException , KafkaError
import json
import sqlite3
import uuid

# Kafka consumer configuration

conf = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka:9092',
    'group.id': uuid.uuid4,
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
    'enable.auto.commit': False  # Disable auto commit to manually commit offsets
}

consumer = Consumer(conf)
consumer.subscribe(['pokemon'])

# SQLite database configuration
conn = sqlite3.connect('/app/data/pokemon.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()





def insert_into_db(name, description, price, stock):
    cursor.execute('''
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO pokemon (name, description, price, stock) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    ''', (name, description, price, stock))
    conn.commit()


try:
    while True:
        msg = consumer.poll(timeout=1.0)
        if msg is None:
            continue
        if msg.error():
            if msg.error().code() == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
                print('End of partition reached {0}/{1}'.format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))
            elif msg.error():
                raise KafkaException(msg.error())
        else:
            message = json.loads(msg.value().decode('utf-8'))
            name = message.get('name')
            print("Received information of " + name)
            description = message.get('Description')
            price = message.get('price')
            stock = message.get('stock')

            # Insert message data into database
            insert_into_db(name, description, price, stock)
            print([name, description, price, stock])
            # Commit offset after writing to file
            consumer.commit(msg)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
finally:
    consumer.close()
    conn.close()

print("Consumer closed and database connection closed.")

Below you can find details of my code:
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "nc", "-z", "localhost", "2181"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
      timeout: 5s
    
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      


    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "nc", "-z", "localhost", "9092"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
      timeout: 5s

  producer:
    build: ./producer
    depends_on:
      kafka:
        condition: service_healthy


  consumer:
    build: ./consumer
    depends_on:
      producer:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
      server:
         condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - db-data:/app/data  

  server:
    build: ./server

    depends_on:
      - kafka
      
    environment:
      KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092  # Add environment variable for Kafka servers
    volumes:
      - db-data:/app/data  # Mount the shared volume for the database
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"  # Expose port for the Flask app
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /app/data/pokemon.db ]"]  # Check if the database file exists
      interval: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
      timeout: 5s

 
volumes:
  db-data:

producer = Producer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka:9092',  # Kafka broker address
})

 conf = {
'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka:9092',
'group.id': uuid.uuid4,
'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
'enable.auto.commit': False  # Disable auto commit to manually commit offsets
 }

consumer = Consumer(conf)
consumer.subscribe(['pokemon'])

Here is my consumer DockerFile:
FROM python:3.11


WORKDIR /app


RUN pip install confluent-kafka

COPY . /app/

CMD ["python", "./consume.py"]


This is a Python application; are you hitting Why doesn't Python app print anything when run in a detached docker container?

Thank you so much! The fact that I might  not be able to see the output never occured me.
